# JMeter with IDs feed at the end of the API call - doesn't work

Tags: csv, jmeter

I need to hit api that has the mongoId at the end. Ids I will feed to the script from CSV. For unknown reason it doesn't work with error that the call is wrong at the first Id character. I had txt file and converted to CSV and it is still not working. 
Original call that works:
[image]

This call has Ids from the file and it doesn't work:
[image]

The failed errors are:
[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for your explanation and help.
JMeter version is 3.3.

Update to UBK:
Doesn't help. I still get the error: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 51: https://qa1.credifi.com/cre-data/property/us/a/a/a/53bb06e8cbda7100842f80ff

```
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:398)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:498)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:424)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Update with changed screenshot. [image]

Update, latest output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the HTTP Request configuration:

- Server Name or IP must only contains ${site} which should be the host name
- The path should be in Path field so you would have:

> /cre-data/property/us/a/a/${PropIds}

Comment: Doesn't help. I still get the error: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 51: https://qa1.credifi.com/cre-data/property/us/a/a/a/5

Comment: I think the problem is that java interpreting /5 as some sort of extended character and fails.

Comment: Can you show what you changed through a screenshot ?Thank you

Comment: Sure. See above.

Comment: Can you show all tabs of View Result Tree for failing sampler and also check there is no invalid/invisible character in the csv that contains PropsId?

Comment: Ids:53bb93b9cbda7100843353e8,
53bb06e8cbda7100842f80ff,
53bb074bcbda7100842f88ec,
53bb0109cbda7100842efafa,
53bb35e6cbda71008431b27d, no additional character.

Comment: I have tested similar request (same path /cre-data/property/us/a/a/a/53bb06e8cbda7100842f80ff) with JMeter mirror server without issue both in 3.3 and 4.0. So I suspect ${PropsID} contains a bad char, can you erase it and write it again ? and show also CSV Dataset

Comment: Wow indeed the file is corrupted at the middle, but was failing even at the first records. Thanks a lot.